# How to display multiple images in a new window using popup from database in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

What I would really like to do is have a ViewImage button on container so that when that is clicked, the images are displayed on a new page . How would I do that?
asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height ="40" Width ="60" Eval(("Cust_ID"),"~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID={0}) ")  %>'
 onclick="CreatepopUp1(this.src);" />

Private Sub CusImgShow()
        Try

```
        'Const SQL As String = "SELECT COALESCE(Civilimg1, civilimg2) AS  civilid  FROM [NewCus] WHERE [Cust_ID] = @Cust_ID"
        Const SQL As String = "SELECT Civilimg1,civilimg2 FROM [NewCus] WHERE [Cust_ID] = @Cust_ID2"
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(SQL, myConnection)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_ID", Request.QueryString("Cust_ID"))
        'Dim adr As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        If myReader.Read Then
            Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG"
            Response.BinaryWrite(myReader("Civilimg1"))
            Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG"
            Response.BinaryWrite(myReader("civilimg2"))
        End If

        myReader.Close()

        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: i wants display Civilimg1 and civilimg2 images on click by this onclick="CreatepopUp1(this.src);" />

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a page that will show one image at a time.

**Example:** `~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID={Cust_ID}&type={ImageType}`.

Then you will update you **asp.net** code similar to this (you could improve this, VB.net is not my strongest point):

```
Const SQL As String = "SELECT @ImageType FROM [NewCus] WHERE [Cust_ID] = @Cust_ID"
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(SQL, myConnection)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_ID", Request.QueryString("Cust_ID"))
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageType", Request.QueryString("ImageType"))

myConnection.Open()
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

If myReader.Read Then
    Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG"
    Response.BinaryWrite(myReader(Request.QueryString("ImageType")))
End If
```

Then in your first **aspx** page (I'm guessing you already have the code for `CreatepopUp1`, right?):

```
<a href="[URL to second page]" onclick="CreatepopUp1(this.src);" />Click here see images</a>
```

And in the **aspx** of the second page (the one that opens):

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height ="40" Width ="60" ImageUrl="~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID=15&ImageType=Civilimg1' />
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height ="40" Width ="60" ImageUrl="~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID=15&ImageType=Civilimg2' />
```

Of course, use your own `Cust_ID` values or set them from the code behind.

Comment: Line 100:                                 
Line 101:                                  <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>   
Line 102:                                  <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height ="20" Width ="40" 
Line 103:                                                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval(("Cust_ID"),"~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID={Cust_ID}&type={ImageType}) ")  %>' 
Line 104:                                                          a href="~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx" onclick="CreatepopUp1(this.src);" />Click here see images</a>

Comment: two images Civilimg1,civilimg2 from database to show by this onclick onclick="CreatepopUp1(this.src);" />

Comment: Take them step by step. First, make sure your secondary page is correctly displaying the image. This means that URL's like `/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID=15&ImageType=Civilimg` should display a valid image. Have you managed to do this?

Comment: SmartDEV i want clarifying this area /crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID=15&ImageType=Civilimg